# Pygame and Keyboard modules combination, True loop breaking abruptly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a code which moves a 0 up, down, left and right using WASD keys and the keyboard module for python!

I am not sure what to do and I haven't tried anything yet...

**This is the code!**

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import keyboard;

def draw():
    pygame.init();
    x=1280
    y=720
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 24)
    black=(0, 0, 0)
    white=(255, 255, 255)
    text = font.render('0', True, black, white)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    x=x/2; y=y/2;
    textRect.center=(x, y)
    screen.fill((white))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)


    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            y = y - 5;
            textRect.center = (x, y)
            screen.fill((white))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)

        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            x = x - 5;
            textRect.center = (x, y)
            screen.fill((white))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            x = x + 5;
            textRect.center = (x, y)
            screen.fill((white))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            y = y + 5;
            textRect.center = (x, y)
            screen.fill((white))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit();
                quit();
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__=="__main__":
    draw()
```

**This is the error**

Here is a gif of the error(*I don't have the reputation yet to upload it here!*)

*link to gif: https://gfycat.com/GlossyCheerfulEstuarinecrocodile*

*The actual result should be the zero moving up...*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any error at the link you provided: just a white screen with O in the center and flashing small windows with a text so small it impossible to read.

When I tried to run your code, the error was:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 292, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

So, I ran it as an administrator with 'sudo' and was able to move zero '0' with the keyboard.

```
sudo python3.7 object_type.py
```

Comment: Alexander, I tried your method by running command prompt as administrator and running the .py file... But I got the same error with the 0 disappearing once a key is pressed... I myself can run the code without being administrator, but I get the same error

Comment: No need to worry Alexander, I found the issue! It was related to me apparently using python 3.7 32-bit rather than 64x. I re-installed python 64x and pygame and now it works just fine!